# Can i put 'page' at the bottom of each page?

Tags: footer

I would like to use wp-admin to make a "page" which is used at the very botton of each pages. The bottom part would look like the below

> Home | Tips | Services | Downloads | Workshops | Testimonials | Resources | Contact us

but on top of that it will be complex. A logo+links+images. Something you would find on a page rather then a menu

How do i create a page with the editor and have it display at the bottom of each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite grasp why you'd want to include a page "on the bottom of each page", rather than putting the "logo+links+images" in the footer and creating a [menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) below that.

That being said, in order to achieve what you want, create the page and include the following in your theme's *footer.php* (the below code example assumes that that page's ID is 83 and/or its [slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug) "bottom-page", change it accordingly):

```
// query for the page using either (not both!) one of the two following lines
$bottom_page_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=83' );
$bottom_page_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=bottom-page' );

// loop through the query (even though it's just one page)
while ( $bottom_page_query->have_posts() ) : $bottom_page_query->the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;

// reset post data (important, don't leave out!)
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: For those wondering why this would be needed ... my example (and this was exactly the answer I needed) was that I had a "page" which was really just a snippet of data I wanted the site owner to be able to edit: Store Hours. I could include the hours throughout the site with short codes in the content editors, but needed a way to access the editable page in the footer to include it there too. (the example as provided by the OP does seem to suggest a Menu is the better option, but there is a legit need for exactly this feature)

Comment: I'd say a quick little plugin, that stores the opening hours as an option might be the better alternative for you, @thagemann

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) function in your `footer.php` template file:

```
<?php
$footer_page = get_page($id = 147);
echo apply_filters('the_content', $footer_page->post_content);
?>
```

Alternative approaches:

- Create a custom [menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) for use in the footer. This may not be an option if you really need the flexibility of a page, but note that you can add CSS classes to each menu item. Coupling that to custom background images for each item may be powerful enough.
- Hard-code the footer part. I prefer to edit HTML in a real editor anyway. Depending on who needs to be able to make changes, this may be a good option. Use [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to pull in your custom footer part wherever you need.